# Transaction Nonce deterring Re-entrancy Attack?

Tags: reentrant-attacks

Why doesn't the use of transaction nonce deter re-entrancy attack?

Answer (score 2):

The transaction nonce applies to the entire transaction, including all internal calls made by different contracts to each other as part of that transaction. So it has no relevance to reentrancy, which involves inserting unexpected calls into the control flow within a single transaction.